# Tapjoy (v 11.7.0) offerwall does not show offers when proguard is enable

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, tapjoy

I prepared the simple project which shows the problem. 
I modified tapjoy SDK demo project. I added there only grandle and proguard rules. 
Here problem occures: https://github.com/klakiers/tapjoy-proguard-problem

[image]

Proguard file: https://github.com/klakiers/tapjoy-proguard-problem/blob/master/app/proguard-project-debug.txt

When proguard works turn off everything is fine. Offerwall shows offers correctly.

Comment: hello i was wondering if anyone here could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215004/tap-joy-offer-wall-integration-with-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

This resolve the problem!
-keepattributes *Annotation*